# Passing parameters to IFRAME in Dynamics CRM using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, dynamics-crm-2015

I've following code snippet to access `http://localhost:80/testsite` in IFRAME. It worked fine but as soon as I went to pass the fields value as parameter nothing get happen. I tried directly access the page from browser with parameters so page is behaving fine. I cannot figure out the things after spending a lot of time. I would like to seek your kind patience on this basic question.

**code Snippet**

```
function forwardValues(){
    var ordername = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("name").getValue();
    var IFrame = Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get("IFRAME_sendvalue");
    var Url = IFrame.getSrc();

    var params = Url.substr(Url.indexOf("?"));

    var param1 = Url+"?ordername="+ordername;

    IFrame.setSrc(param1);

}
```

Comment: Your code snippet uses an unsupported technique. Custom parameters should be passed to HTML web resources using the query string parameter "data". See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309536.aspx for a list of supported query parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use following code:

```
function forwardValues(){
   var ordername = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("name").getValue();
   var IFrame = Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get("IFRAME_sendvalue");
   var Url = IFrame.getSrc();
   if (Url.indexOf("?") != -1)
       Url = Url.substr(0, Url.indexOf("?"));
   var param1 = Url+"?ordername="+ordername;
   IFrame.setSrc(param1);
}
```

Comment: Interesting, it worked fine in IE but not in Chrome and FF

Comment: You will have to master troubleshooting. Following article can help you with it - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/crm/2015/11/29/debugging-custom-javascript-code-in-crm-using-browser-developer-tools/

Comment: Andrii, I can find the my library in IE but not in Chrome and FF. But strange thing is when I set a debugger in library the debugger executed but again nothing gets happen in IFRAME

Comment: There are no miracles. Everything has an explanation. Continue digging.